# How to make a hard disk inaccessible in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I installed two Windows 8. One for work and one for entertainment. They are on separate drives (the first system is on a SSD and the second system is on a HDD). Since I will probably install some "freewares" that might contain threats to the second system, I don't want the virus, if any, to infect my first system. However, currently, the files of the first system are exposed to the second system.
So my question is how I can make the drive inaccessible when I boot from another drive. "Inaccessible" means that any software cannot write or read the data on the disabled drive.

Will removing the letter of a drive help to prevent access of the drive?

Comment: What about creating a virtual machine instead?

Answer (score 1):

If a program poses a thread, it’s usually running as admin already. “root” can do anything, including raw disk access, mounting partitions and whatnot.

So no, nothing short of physically disconnecting power or data will stop malicious software.